# YouTube API v3 batch processing

Tags: java, youtube-api

does YouTube API v3 support batch processing? I've wrote my code using normal individual requests, but it takes forever to execute since it's about 40000 requests .

Answer (score 4):

Yes, batch processing is supported in v3 but not like in v2.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/deprecated#Batch_Processing

"The v3 API supports one of the batch processing use cases that the v2 API had supported. The v3 API's channels.list, channelSections.list, guideCategories.list, playlistItems.list, playlists.list, subscriptions.list, videoCategories.list, and videos.list methods all support an id parameter, which can be used to specify a comma-delimited list of IDs (video IDs, channel IDs, etc.). Using those methods, you can retrieve a list of multiple resources with a single request."