# Batch processing for Youtube Data API in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, batch-processing, youtube-data-api, google-api-client

I am trying to make a request to the Youtube API for multiple video ids, and understand that this is referred to as 'batch processing'.

So far I have successfully made individual requests by appending the video id, request parameters and API key to the following url for the request:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?

becomes:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,player&id=ZYpxsJHVC-0&key=

Using this method I am able to retrieve data for multiple videos by comma separating multiple ids after 'id=' in the request url.  I think that I am doing something similar to the video.list property mentioned in this post: [YouTube API v3 batch processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982722/youtube-api-v3-batch-processing) and documented here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#request

Is there some other batch processing method I should be using instead of adding 50 different video ids to the request url?  Considering I am using Node, it seems like using Google's Node.js client library would make sense, but I couldn't find documentation on how to make specifically Youtube Data API requests.

The API Client Library for Javascript ( https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/batch#batch-request-promise ) actually sounds exactly like what I need because it supports promises, however the doc page doesn't mention how to download it.  I was hoping to find some sort of 'npm install' command, but its not there.  If this is the recommended method for going about retrieving video data for multiple videos, could someone point me in the right direction as far as implementing this library in my project?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Google wants you to call their API Client Library for Javascript directly from their servers, as you can see in [their authSample script](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/samples/authSample.html):

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```

Google has also released Node.js libraries that can be installed using npm.  [These installation instructions](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs) are for the Calendar API, but the package may also include the YouTube API.  Please let us know!